# changing location for standalone.xml.tmp

Tags: jboss, wildfly8

We use wildfly 10.x as an application server. Our setup is much restrictive. So the AS user is not allowed to write to `jboss.server.base.dir/configuration/` but at startup it wants to write the standalone.xml.tmp file to that location.
Is there a way to change the location for that file to `jboss.server.tmp.dir`?

I added also wildfly8 as a tag because it may be also a interesting thing for that version.

Comment: Wildfly allow you change the configuration location directory by setting the `jboss.domain.config.dir` jvm propertie, but not provide any direct way to change location of `standalone_xml_history` directory. You can try change entire `jboss.domain.config.dir` to a new location o another thing that I think you can try is create a symlink for the `standalone_xml_history`.

Comment: The symlink aproach is unfortunately not a solution because wildfly tries to delete the standalone.xml.tmp file.

Comment: My recommendation was create a symlink for `standalone_xml_history` directory, not for files inside this.

Comment: Ah, wildfly 10 generates files directly under configuration, not standalone_xml_history. This is the main cause.

Comment: Yes you are right, the standalone.xml.tmp is created in base config directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the `standalone.xml` during runtime then you can call:

```
standalone.bat --read-only-server-config=standalone.xml
```

That won't touch any file in your configuration folder. Even the `logging.properties` is not touched, if the content is already matching the `standalone.xml`.